# Is relative URL/path possible in Components.utils.import()?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-restartless

Relative URL/path works in overlay XUL, instead of using the full `chrome://............`

I tried and failed to use it with `Components.utils.import()`. Is it possible?

Also noticed: [Bug 628669 - Provide support for relative URLs in Components utils import (JSM, JS modules)](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=628669)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you study the bug you linked, you'll notice that relative imports where implemented as [`XPCOMUtils.importRelative()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/XPCOMUtils.jsm#importRelative%28%29).

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/XPCOMUtils.jsm");
XPCOMUtils.importRelative(this, "bar.jsm");
```

But this will only work from other code modules, but not overlay scripts or `bootstrap.js`.
For those cases, I'd just write a helper function...

Comment: I see... actually the intention was to import a `jsm` script from `bootstrap.js` ie `Components.utils.import('local.jsm');`

Comment: `bootstrap.js` isn't really relative to any `chrome:` URL anyway (or at least the loader doesn't know that)... It is loaded from some `file:` (unpacked) or `jar:` (XPI) URI and you cannot load those using `Cu.import` anyway.